# how to check automatically a parent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

In a `Form` I have a `TreeView` with a checkbox tree. For all child nodes in the tree I want to create an event to check if the root node is checked, and uncheck in the correct situation. For this do I necessarily need an extension class?

Can someone give me a step by step solution? I already tried a lot of solutions; but they don't do anything. I tried to modify my code and it doesn't work. My code is with an extension class.

Is there simple solution available for this?

```
|_| Parent
  |_| Child1
    |_| Child2
|_|Parent2
   |_|Child3
```

This is my `treeView`, before the name is a check box . When `Parent` is check automatically check `Child1 and Child2`. when `Parent2` is check, automatically check `Child3` .

```
namespace Extension
{

    public static class ExtensionClass
    {
        public static List<TreeNode> Parents(this TreeNode node)
        {
            var parents = new List<TreeNode>();
            TreeNode parent=node.Parent;
            while(parent!=null);
            {
                parents.Add(parent);
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
            return parents;
        }

        public static void CheckChildren(this TreeNode node)
        {
            if (!node.Checked)
                return;

            foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
            {
                child.Checked = true;
                child.CheckChildren();
            }
        }

        public static void CheckParentsAndChildren(this TreeNode node)
        {
            node.CheckChildren(); // Check children of current node only.
            TreeNode parent = node.Parent;
            while (parent != null) ;
            {
                parent.Checked = true;
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
        }
    }

}
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

    static class Program
    {
}
```

and in Form2 I have this:

```
using Extension;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
 private bool _checking;
        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
          //  e.Node.CheckParentsAndChildren();
            if (!_checking && e.Node.Checked)
            {
                _checking = true;
                try
                {
                    e.Node.CheckParentsAndChildren();
                }
                finally
                {
                    _checking = false;
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Please make the requirements more clear. From this description we don't know what you want to happen.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, in a minimal example. You don't need to create a subclass of anything - you only need an event handler for the checkbox being ticked.

Comment: Title not reflecting what you need.

Comment: now is more clearly ??

Comment: @uid still we want to see what you have tried.

Comment: I tried with an extension class, and my question is for find something more simple and something to work. But if you still want I can put my code

Comment: As you can see my code is so complicated and don't work . I need a solution .

Comment: straight out of MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also I tried this and doesn't work for me

Comment: It is working. Make sure to bind node_AfterCheck to the treeview's AfterCheck event.

Comment: I put those methods after private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e). it's ok ?

Comment: (Aside: when you added code to this question, you accidentally reverted a good edit that made the wording clearer. If you see a JavaScript message in Stack Overflow to say that the question has been edited whilst you are editing, roll back, refresh and make the edits again, so that changes are not lost. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this should already solve your issue:

```
private void OnTreeViewAfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    var treeView = (TreeView)sender;

    treeView.AfterCheck -= OnTreeViewAfterCheck;
    SetChildCheckedState(e.Node);
    treeView.AfterCheck += OnTreeViewAfterCheck;
}

private void SetChildCheckedState(TreeNode treeNode)
{
    foreach (TreeNode childNode in treeNode.Nodes)
    {
        childNode.Checked = treeNode.Checked;

        // Call recursively if you like
        SetChildCheckedState(childNode);
    }
}
```

If you like, you can put that code into your own method or extension method, but I think it is a quite easy code. If you need a more complex logic please describe it here.

Comment: Thank you so mach, you don't know how mach I search for this answer  :*